# Lite (ansi c 89) os for custom cpu?

Tags: c, operating-system, minix

A friend of mine created a 16-bit stack based CPU on an fpga and I've been developing an ANSI C 89 compiler for it. He needs a file system and networking so he's now working on an os for it based on minix, but he's doing it on a pascal based compiler he wrote and it's going to take a while. Ideally we would like to be able to use our C compiler to build the minix source in it's entirety but I am a few weeks away from finishing the compiler and I'm sure it will be a while before it's up to the task.  I would like to know if anyone has had any success porting minix to a custom CPU and what we should look out for, or if there are any alternative open source os's that are lightweight that we should be considering. Keep in mind that this is a custom c compiler so I don't offer any of gcc's toolchain bells and whistles.

Comment: I was going to recommend [L4Ka](http://www.l4ka.org/english/index.php), but it's written in C++...

Comment: Maybe Xinu?  It might be similar to minix, and I think there are some interesting ports that were made using it.